# How to create KSQL table join

Tags: ksqldb

I want to make a Kafka KTable which joins with two tables/stream
The following is an example of the json

```
-- example messages for item-topic
{
  "itemid":"1a",
  "description":"Item A"
}

{
  "itemid":"1b",
  "description":"Item B"
}
-- example messages for order-topic
{
    "order_id":"1",
    "items":[
        { "itemId":"1a", "qty": 1 },
        { "itemId":"1b", "qty": 2 }
    ]
}
```

```
CREATE STREAM OrderStream WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='order-topic', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
CREATE STREAM ItemStream WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='item-topic', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

I am unsure how to create Stream or table that shows

```
{
    "order_id":"1",
    "items":[
        { "itemId":"1a", "qty": 1, "description":"Item A" },
        { "itemId":"1b", "qty": 2, "description":"Item B" }
    ]
}
```